# How to turn my linux laptop into wireless repeater?

Tags: linux, wifi

**I need to use my laptop to extend the range of my wireless router.**

I have a Samsung laptop with Fedora19 installed (but those should be irrelevant for a good answer). My wireless card supports master mode (`iw list` listing includes `AP` mode).

The card is:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

I am trying to follow this resource [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode) but am getting errors and my knowledge is too limited to get me through them.

```
[sci@localhost ~]$ su -c "iwconfig wlp1s0 mode master"
Password: 
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlp1s0 ; Invalid argument.
```

Following the Atheros specific advice at the middle of the page:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module ath_pci not found.
```

I am very surprised that the procedure is not trivial, and that a dedicated application doesn't exist. How should I approach this? Further reading is in order, if it is focused on the problem at hand!

Comment: Normally I would have 2x WiFi card and create a bridge from one to the other. So 1 card is communicating in dual direction with the source, bridging the connection to the second wireless card, and that is communicating in dual direction with the devices that are further away.

Comment: Along the lines of what DanijelJames said, I would suggest somehow emulating two WiFi cards with two different MAC addresses. Then you can use one to access the wireless network, and the other to be an access point. Unfortunately I do not know how how you would go about emulating two WiFi cards, although I do believe it is possible.

Comment: @DanijelJames, I believe (==have heard) that this can be achieved with only one card. I own a tiny feeble USB wifi dongle, so two cards could work, would also be an answer to my question.

Comment: Most likely this link has all the information for today: [Arch Linux - Software access point 1.2 Wireless client and software AP with a single Wi-Fi device](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Software_access_point#Wireless_client_and_software_AP_with_a_single_Wi-Fi_device) (even the example NIC is most probably an ath9k just like in OP).

Comment: Forgot that to be a wireless repeater in bridge mode, 4A mode (aka 4addr / WDS ...) is required between the original AP and the repeater, but people don't expect to have to tinker with the AP, and most often the AP can't be.

Comment: @A.B this looks like a complete answer. I do not need to solve the problem anymore, so I'll not Accept it but the voting mechanism is still in place.

Comment: The amount of effort to have a working answer is long (I know, I'm using 4A mode (mostly for testing rather than for actual use)) and even depends on possible disruption from network tools around (I elected to hide the wireless interfaces on the STA side in their own namespace so NetworkManager wouldn't interact). I'm not ready yet to do an answer that would work as-is, should the person looking for this be able to reconfigure hostapd on the AP side too. Maybe in a few weeks or months...